# Python 3.7.0- where python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed python 3.7.0 at my new laptop which runs with Windows.

However, when I enter at the command prompt `where python3` then I get `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

But when I enter at the command prompt `where python` then I get `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe.`

I am quite confused because (if I remember right) when I had installed python 3.6.6 at my other laptop then essentially the opposite was happening; `where python3` was returning the latter message and `where python` was returning the former message and for me this makes more sense since I have installed in both cases a python 3 version.

Why is this happening?
What am I missing?

Just to also mention that I run this python with PyCharm and everything works right so far as a python 3 version but I was just wondering about that.

Comment: No executable called `python3` is installed with Python 3.x on Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks @AKX for the comment. Yes, obviously this is the reason but I was expecting that python 3.7.0 would be accompanied by a python3 executable. Or essentially this makes no difference if its name is `python` or `python3`?

Comment: There's no difference if you only have a single version of Python installed on your machine.

Comment: @AKX: Yes, I have only one version since it is the only one I installed on my newly bought laptop this couple of days. So there is no difference I guess. It was quite confusing for me because it should be a python 3 version but only `where python` was returning a proper response so I was wondering if I have not exactly installed a python 3 version...

Comment: @asynts: Yes `python -- version` returns `Python 3.7.0` as expected. So I guess I am ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running python only in cmd, if you have only one version of python installed then there is no need to specify python3.

Answer (score 2):

You are guided by the false belief, that the python executable must suffixed by it's version number. If you wanted to you could rename the `python.exe` file into `monkey.exe` and it would still work (if you call it correctly).

`python3` is the default name for Python 3 on Ubuntu (I assume that's were you saw it). That way it can be distinguished from Python 2 which is already named `python`.

If you want to check if your executable is the correct one, you can ask the binary for it's version:

```
<path-to-file>\python.exe --version
```